# Searching file for the same string twice and printing both separately

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics

I am a beginner python programmer with a search question. I need to locate a string of DNA in a DNA file. The issue is that I do not know where the string appears in the file, it appears twice, and I need to know both locations. My current program can only find the first string and I am having difficulty having it continue the search to find the second.  My two ideas that I have have both failed but I think only because I do not understand how to use the functions. Here they are:

1. use .seek() to find the first string of DNA I need and set that as the starting point for a second search. My problem is that I do not know exactly where the DNA strings are, so I tried to set my seek location to the DNA string.  This wont work however, as the data needs to be in bytes to find a location, not a string.  I tried to use .index() the location of the DNA string and setting that as a variable, but that also does not work.
2. Use .split() to split the DNA text file after the first DNA string was found then running a second search on the right half of the break. I thought this would work, but I only end up with an error reading:

   IndexError: list index out of range

specifically, I am writing .split('str')[1] to use the second half of the string.

Assuming my logic is correct in the program, would these approaches work? Does anyone have a different idea they think I should try?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you post how your seek and split methods are being used? And did you write seek and split, or are they part of an existing API, (bioinformatics or otherwise)? (If the former, please post them. If the latter, please tell us the name of the library.)

Answer (score 2):

I read your problem as "I am trying to find the locations of a DNA subsequence." Does the following example represent what you are trying to achieve? Let me know if I am oversimplifying your question and I can revise.

```
>>> import re
>>> dna = 'AGTCTCCCGGATTTGGATTTAA' #super short, but just for proof of concept
>>> subseq = 'ATTT' #sequence you want to find within dna
>>> for location in re.finditer(subseq, dna):
...     print 'start: %d end: %d' % (location.start(), location.end())

start: 10 end: 14
start: 16 end: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

How large is your file?  If it is not prohibitively long, you could use the naive approach:

```
file = open("filename.text", r)
genome = file.read()
file.close()
genome_length = len(genome)
pattern = "ATCT" #or whatever your pattern is
pattern_length = len(pattern)
pattern_locations = []
for i in range(genome_length - pattern_length - 1):
    if pattern == genome[i:i+pattern_length]:
        pattern_locations.append(i)
return pattern_locations
```

However, if the genome is long then it would require more sophisticated algorithms in order to search in a reasonable time (such as constructing a suffix tree)